# if checkbox toggle checked then make a input field required in the toggle div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I use a script to toggle some div´s with javascript. I want to make some input fields "required" in the toggle div if the checkbox is checked to show the toggle div.

Can someone figure it out  ? that is work?

```js
function show(id) { 
    if(document.getElementById) { 
        var mydiv = document.getElementById(id); 
        mydiv.style.display = (mydiv.style.display=='block'?'none':'block'); 
    }
} 

var $myCheckbox = $('#neu_ma'),
$required = $('.required');

$myCheckbox.on('click', function() {
this.checked ? $required.prop('required', true) : $required.prop('required', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" name="berechtigungsantrag">
<fieldset>
 <legend><input type="checkbox" name="neu_ma" id="neu_ma" onclick="javascript:show('neuer_mitarbeiter');"> Neuer Mitarbeiter </legend>
     
<div style="display: none" id="neuer_mitarbeiter">
         
                <label for="eintritt_datum">Eintrittsdatum:</label>
                <div><input type="date" name="eintritt_datum" id="eintritt_datum" class="required" /></div>
     
                <label for="befristung_datum">Befristungsdatum:</label>
  <div><input type="date" name="befristung_datum" id="befristung_datum"/></div>
    
</div>

    </fieldset><!-- End of fieldset -->
 
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Speichern" name=save />

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

You're trying to listen an element id that does not exist(neu_ma) - you haven't given your checkbox an id.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="neu_ma" onclick="javascript:show('neuer_mitarbeiter');">
```

So just give it an ID:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="neu_ma" id="neu_ma" onclick="javascript:show('neuer_mitarbeiter');">
```

---

**This is just an example how you could do it:**

Add some specific class to inputs that need to be affected by the state of your checkbox.

I made an example HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" />
    <input type="text" class="required" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" class="required" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, some of the inputs have a class called "required".

Next I check checkbox status(checked or not). And depending on the result make elements with "required" class required(or not) using jQuery's prop() method.

**Working example:**

```js
var $myCheckbox = $('#myCheckbox'),
    $required = $('.required');

$myCheckbox.on('click', function() {
    this.checked ? $required.prop('required', true) : $required.prop('required', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" />
    <input type="text" class="required" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" class="required" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: yes but this dont work if is the input field in my toogle div. Can you take my script an figured it out with toogle div?

Comment: I changed my answer. First part should answer your question.